# How to create this kind a menu using wp menu?

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-nav-walker, wp-nav-menu-item

I want to create below code using [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/). How do I create this code using `wp_nav_menu`? Also how to change UL class page to page using `wp_nav_menu`?

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav hatch-main-nav-inner hatch-main-nav-inner--red">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/co-working">Co-working <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <div class="hatch-secondary-menu">
                <a class="hatch-secondary-menu-item hatch-secondary-menu-item--active" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/co-working">Overview</a>
                <a class="hatch-secondary-menu-item" href="#">Pricing</a>
                <a class="hatch-secondary-menu-item" href="#">Perks</a>
                <a class="hatch-secondary-menu-item" href="#">Locations</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/start-ups">Start-ups</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/membership">Membership</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/events">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

I used this code for now:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( 
    array( 
        'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav hatch-main-nav-inner hatch-main-nav-inner--red', 
        'container' => false, 
        'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 
        'items_wrap' => '<ul>%3$s</ul>', 
        'depth' => 1, 

    ) 
);
?>
```

Using this code I can view main URL, but I don't know how to view sub menu items.

Comment: what you did so far? show us your efforts if you stuck then will help you there.

Comment: I used this code for now <?php

    wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu_class'     => 'navbar-nav hatch-main-nav-inner hatch-main-nav-inner--red',
    'container' => false,
   'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
     'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
     'depth' => 1,
    
    ) );
    
   ?>  using this code i can view main url but i don't no how to view sub menu items

Comment: Kindly read this https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/function-examination-wp_nav_menu--wp-25525 it will help you to solve this.

Comment: formatting, grammar, hyperlink, added comment with code to question